# Azure IoT SDK C: Error 401 when connecting to Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, esp32, azure-iot-sdk

**OS and version used:** Ubuntu 18.04

**SDK version used:** Release Dec. 13, 2018

**Target:** ESP32.

**Description of the issue:**

I am trying to connect the ESP32 to my Blob storage. I am getting an HTTP error 401 (unauthorized access).
I am using the example: iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob_mb.
I tried connecting using just the Shared Access Key in my connection string, but this did not work (no connection). After that I generated an SAS token in Azure (Storage Accounts -> -> Shared Access Signature) and plugged that in into my connection string.
My connection string looks like this:

```
static const char* connectionString = "HostName=<Host name>;DeviceId=<Device ID>;SharedAccessSignature=<inserted here without the "?" at the beginning>";
```

Q1: Why is there a "?" in front of the token? When I look at the connection string, at SharedAccessSignature=.. I don't see the "?".

I also set up the Endpoint in Azure under IoT Hub -> Upload files.
In the example, I am using the option SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES.

Q2: What does that mean? I am not so familiar with basic encryption and should probably read up on that.

Q3: Why am I getting an 401 error? What could be a possible solution?

**Log:**

Initializing SNTP
ESP platform sntp inited!
Time is not set yet. Connecting to WiFi and getting time over NTP. timeinfo.tm_year:70
Waiting for system time to be set... tm_year:0[times:1]
Starting the IoTHub client sample upload to blob with multiple blocks...

Info: Waiting for TLS connection
Info: Waiting for TLS connection
Info: Waiting for TLS connection
Info: Waiting for TLS connection

Error: Time:Thu Jan 17 22:06:00 2019 File:/home/julian/eclipse-workspace/chaze-esp32/components/esp-azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_ll_uploadtoblob.c Func:send_http_request Line:142 HTTP code was 401

Error: Time:Thu Jan 17 22:06:00 2019 File:/home/julian/eclipse-workspace/chaze-esp32/components/esp-azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_ll_uploadtoblob.c Func:IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_step1and2 Line:494 unable to HTTPAPIEX_ExecuteRequest

Error: Time:Thu Jan 17 22:06:00 2019 File:/home/julian/eclipse-workspace/chaze-esp32/components/esp-azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/iothub_client/src/iothub_client_ll_uploadtoblob.c Func:IoTHubClient_LL_UploadMultipleBlocksToBlob_Impl Line:768 error in IoTHubClient_LL_UploadToBlob_step1
Received unexpected result FILE_UPLOAD_ERROR

hello world failed to upload
Press any key to continue

[Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c) is the link to the GitHub Repo.

The example can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob_mb/iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob_mb.c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the 401 error: Use MSFT Baltimore certificate in the code.
To get rid of the panic on the ESP: Look at this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/814).

Answer (score 1):

> I generated an SAS token in Azure (Storage Accounts -> -> Shared Access Signature) and plugged that in into my connection string. My connection string looks like this:
>
> `static const char* connectionString = "HostName=<Host name>;DeviceId=<DeviceID>;SharedAccessSignature=<inserted here without the "?" at the beginning>";`
>
> Q1: Why is there a "?" in front of the token? When I look at the connection string, at SharedAccessSignature=.. I don't see the "?".

After registering a device on IoTHub you will need to retrieve it's connection string to use on this example. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/quickstart-send-telemetry-c#register-a-device) an example on how to register and retrieve the connection string from a device on IoTHub.

> I also set up the Endpoint in Azure under IoT Hub -> Upload files. In the example, I am using the option SET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES.
>
> Q2: What does that mean? I am not so familiar with basic encryption and should probably read up on that.

That Flag is used when compiling the SDK for your device. See [the CMake File](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/samples/iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob_mb/CMakeLists.txt):

```
#Conditionally use the SDK trusted certs in the samples
if(${use_sample_trusted_cert})
    add_definitions(-DSET_TRUSTED_CERT_IN_SAMPLES)
    include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/certs)
    set(iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob_mb_c_files ${iothub_client_sample_upload_to_blob_mb_c_files} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/certs/certs.c)
endif()
```

> Q3: Why am I getting an 401 error? What could be a possible solution?

Make sure you configure file upload on Azure IoTHub correctly - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload and use the correct connection string on the sample. Also leverage [the ESP8266 sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-arduino-huzzah-esp8266-get-started#connect-feather-huzzah-esp8266-with-the-sensor-and-your-computer) that should have similar steps as the ESP32 configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it later!